# Decompressing time-To-Sample table (STTS) in an MP4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hex, mp4, compression

i have an mp4 video byte array and i need to generate a thumbnail for it using its middle frame (e.g. if the video length is 10 seconds then i need to get the picture from 5th second).

i managed to parse through the file and extract its boxes (atom). i have also managed to get the video length from the mvhd box. also i managed to extract 
1. the time-To-Sample table from stts box, 
2. the sample-To-Chunk table from stcs box,
3. the chunk-Offset table from stco box, 
4. the sample Size table from stsz box,
5. the Sync Sample table from stss box

i know that all the actual media are available in the mdat box and that i need to correlate the above table to find the exact frame offset in the file but my question is how? the tables data seems to be compressed (specially the time-To-Sample table) but i don't know how decompress them.

any help is appreciated.

below are code samples

code to convert byte to hex

```
public static char[] bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;

        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];            
    }
    return hexChars;
}
```

code for getting the box offset

```
final static String MOOV                          = "6D6F6F76";
final static String MOOV_MVHD                     = "6D766864";
final static String MOOV_TRAK                     = "7472616B";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA                = "6D646961";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF           = "6D696E66";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL      = "7374626C";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STSD = "73747364";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STTS = "73747473";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STSS = "73747373";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STSC = "73747363";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STCO = "7374636F";
final static String MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STSZ = "7374737A";

static int getBox(char[] s, int offset, String type) {
    int typeOffset = -1;
    for (int i = offset*2; i<s.length; ) {
        String sizeHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, i, i + 8));
        String typeHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, i + 8, i + 16));
        int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeHex, 16);

        if (typeHex.equals(type)) {
            typeOffset = (i/2);
            break;
        } else if (typeHex.equals(MOOV) 
            || typeHex.equals(MOOV_TRAK) 
            || typeHex.equals(MOOV_TRAK_MDIA) 
            || typeHex.equals(MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF)
            || typeHex.equals(MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL)) {
            int x = (i/2) + 8;
            typeOffset = getBox(s, x, type);
            if (typeOffset>-1) {
                break;
            } 
        }
        i+=(size*2);
    }

    return typeOffset;
}
```

code for getting the duration and timescale

```
static int[] getDuration(char[] s) {
    int mvhdOffset = getBox(s, 0, MOOV_MVHD);
    int timeScaleStart = (mvhdOffset*2) + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 4)*2;
    int timeScaleEnd   = (mvhdOffset*2) + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4)*2;

    int durationStart  = (mvhdOffset*2) + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4)*2;
    int durationEnd    = (mvhdOffset*2) + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4)*2;

    String timeScaleHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, timeScaleStart, timeScaleEnd));
    String durationHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, durationStart, durationEnd));

    int timeScale = Integer.parseInt(timeScaleHex, 16);
    int duration = Integer.parseInt(durationHex, 16);

    int[] result = {duration, timeScale};
    return result;
}
```

code to get the time-To-Sample table

```
static int[][] getTimeToSampleTable(char[] s, int trakOffset) {
    int offset = getBox(s, trakOffset, MOOV_TRAK_MDIA_MINF_STBL_STTS);
    int sizeStart = offset*2;
    int sizeEnd   = offset*2 + (4)*2;

    int typeStart = offset*2 + (4)*2;
    int typeEnd   = offset*2 + (4 + 4)*2;

    int noOfEntriesStart = offset*2 + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3)*2;
    int noOfEntriesEnd   = offset*2 + (4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 4)*2;

    String sizeHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, sizeStart, sizeEnd));
    String typeHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, typeStart, typeEnd));
    String noOfEntriesHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, noOfEntriesStart, noOfEntriesEnd));

    int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeHex, 16);
    int noOfEntries = Integer.parseInt(noOfEntriesHex, 16);

    int[][] timeToSampleTable = new int[noOfEntries][2];

    for (int i = 0; i<noOfEntries; i++) {
        int sampleCountStart = noOfEntriesEnd + ((i)*((4 + 4)*2));
        int sampleCountEnd   = noOfEntriesEnd + ((i)*((4 + 4)*2)) + (4)*2;

        int sampleDurationStart = noOfEntriesEnd + ((i)*((4 + 4)*2)) + (4)*2;
        int sampleDurationEnd   = noOfEntriesEnd + ((i)*((4 + 4)*2)) + (4 + 4)*2;

        String sampleCountHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, sampleCountStart, sampleCountEnd));
        String sampleDurationHex = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, sampleDurationStart, sampleDurationEnd));

        timeToSampleTable[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(sampleCountHex, 16);
        timeToSampleTable[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(sampleDurationHex, 16);
    }

    return timeToSampleTable;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: not yet unfortunantly

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC 14496-12 Standard describes all the steps you need.
Appendix 7 provides steps for decoding. Section 8 describes the tables.

Hope this helps.